# Is the Final value theorem applicable for some non-causal signals?

Tags: discrete-signals, z-transform, digital

A digital signal $x[n]$ is zero at odd sample numbers and one at even sample numbers.

What will be the value of this Signal at $n = \infty$?
Not exactly sure, but I thought that infinity (as a integer), has equal probability of being even/odd. That's why the signal should equal $1/2$ at infinity. But, my college mates are saying that the value should be $0$, as the signal's $\mathcal{Z}$-transform $X(z)$ is always zero.

However, it is unconvincing that $X(z)$ at $z=0$ would define $x[n]$ at $n=\infty$, because $X(z)$ at $z=\infty$ is zero, but $x[0]=1$.

Comment: Why not just accept that $\lim_{n\to \infty}x[n]$ doesn't exist? The $Z$-transform of $x[n]$ doesn't exist either.

Comment: (A) Where does non-causal systems come into this?  It's a signal!  (B) the final value theorem is about _signals_, not _systems_.

Comment: A signal can't be non-causal.  Signals just _are_.  A _system_ can be non-causal, if its response doesn't come strictly after its input.

Comment: @TimWescott: What you say makes sense, of course, but it is not uncommon to call signals "non-causal" if they're non-zero for $n<0$. If Proakis does so (e.g., in the 3rd edition of "Digital Signal Processing" p. 198), then I guess we're allowed to do so too. "Two-sided" may be a better term, but "non-causal" is at least as clear.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $10101\ldots$ doesn't converge, so the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}x[n]$ doesn't exist. You can't use the Final Value Theorem here because the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform of $x[n]$ doesn't exist either since the corresponding power series diverges:

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x[n]z^{-n}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}z^{-2n}\longrightarrow\infty$$

But the answer to the question in the title

> Is the Final value theorem applicable for some non-causal signals?

is in the affirmative. The only conditions are that the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}x[n]$ exists, and that the $\mathcal{Z}$-transform $X(z)$ exists. This implies that there are either no poles on the unit circle ($\lim_{n\to\infty}x[n]=0$), or only a single pole at $z=1$ ($\lim_{n\to\infty}x[n]\neq 0$).

Take as an example the non-causal sequence

$$x[n]=\left(\frac12\right)^nu[n]+x_{\infty}u[n]+2^nu[-n-1]\tag{1}$$

Clearly, we have $\lim_{n\to\infty}x[n]=x_{\infty}\tag{2}$

Its (bilateral) $\mathcal{Z}$-transform is given by

$$X(z)=\frac{1}{1-\frac12 z^{-1}}+\frac{x_{\infty}}{1-z^{-1}}-\frac{1}{1-2z^{-1}},\qquad 1<|z|<2\tag{3}$$

The Final Value Theorem gives

$$\lim_{z\to 1}(z-1)X(z)=\lim_{z\to 1}zx_{\infty}=x_{\infty}\tag{4}$$

Comment: You could zero out the signal for $n < 0$ and get a z-transform that will converge for $|z| > 1$, similar to the z-transform of $u(n)$.  Then you could show the intuitively obvious fact that it doesn't settle to zero at infinity.

Comment: @TimWescott: Yes, but the point was to show that under the specified conditions you can simply use the FVT also with the bilateral bilateral Z-transform of a non-causal signal.